# WKWebView How to display links to http: pages

Tags: ios, wkwebview, app-transport-security

I have a `WKWebView` which will display users' webpages using links gathered online.
Sometimes these links are `http:` which are blocked by `ATS`.
I've tried simply changing the links to `https:`, which works sometimes.

However, very often I get an error "An `SSL` error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made".

Sometimes the page simply redirects to the `http:`, which gets blocked again.
Other times the `https:` page is simply "Not found".
Removing `http:` only results in `"Unsupported URL"` error.

Is there any way to get `WKWebView` to show these pages?

PLEASE DON"T suggest `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, or even per-domain exceptions (I do not know in advance what the domains will be).
The pages load perfectly on Safari, and even mobile safari, so it must be possible.

Comment: There's an `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` exception key that allows arbitrary urls to load in web views.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much Dan. That works a treat. You saved the day :-)

Answer (score 9):

So, the short answer is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`, which will work great in iOS 10.  However, if you try to run with that in your Info.plist on an iOS 9 device, it won't work.

If you want this to work on both iOS 9 and iOS 10, what Apple is recommending that you do is to put **both** `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` **AND** `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` in your Info.plist.

In iOS 9, since it doesn't recognize the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` entry, it will allow all http content in the app (including your WKWebview).  This isn't ideal, but as long as you are ensuring your critical connections elsewhere are secure, having Apple enforce it really doesn't do much.

In iOS 10 (which most of your users should be running) iOS will ignore the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` if it also sees `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`.  This means the rest of your app network communications will need to follow ATS's security requirements, while the WKWebView and UIWebView does not.  This isn't a great solution, but it is the one recommended by Apple engineers when you need to support both iOS 9 and 10.

Note that when Apple does start to require justifications for ATS exceptions, the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` entry is one of the ones that will trigger the need to justification.  But, it is better than having `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` by itself, and you can put that in your justification and it should be accepted by Apple.

Answer (score 5):

As posted in [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/wkwebview/how-to-load-http-content-in-wkwebview-and-uiwebview), add a top level property `NSAppTransportSecurity` in `info.plist`, then if the iOS version is 10 and above, add a boolean entry for `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` in this dictionary, otherwise `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, such that the plist entry looks like

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```