# UI Webview or WK Webview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, wkwebview

In my app, I want to open a website. Earlier I used `UIWebview` in Swift 3.0 and it was all good. But as I read that `WKWebview` should be used now, with `WKWebview` the website does not show in the app. I am confused that what can be the reason that why website works with `UIWebview` but not with `WKWebview`. I tried several other websites which are working completely fine with both `UIWebview` and `WKWebview`. Can some one please suggest what can be the issue here.

Also, if I use `UIWebView`, will my app be rejected.

Below is the sample code from Apple that I am using.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "http://www.spectrum-ag.de/de/") //here I put my website url
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Url are you trying to display? I assume "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview" is working fine?

Comment: http://www.spectrum-ag.de/de/

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41576608/2961412. The url is not a https-url, so it will be blocked by the ATS

Comment: `view.addSubView(webView)` other code looks good

Answer (score 2):

The code works fine. Is your url http or https?
You can still use UIWebView, it will not be rejected. UIWebView is not deprecated. Apple just recommends to use WKWebView, because it has better performance than UIWebView.

Comment: I had to unblock http, now it works, thanks a lot. could you please tell me how can I add a navigation bar at top of view controller in which I am using WK Webview. My View controller in the story board has a navigation bar at top but when I run my app I cannot see the navigation bar at top , although website is loaded properly

Comment: Did you use Editor -> Embed in to add a navigation bar? I tried, and I saw the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that perfectly works. But I cannot display at tile in navigation bar. Also I would like to know is it ok to embed the view controller into navigation controller when I just want to have a top navigation bar to show the title only

Comment: I don't know whether I get your meaning. Do you mean you just need a navigation bar not a navigation controller? If you use a navigation controller, you will find a navigation item under your view controller in story board. And click it, it has an attribute named title(on the right side bar, fourth item). Or you can set it by code. self.title = "" or self.navigationItem.title = "".

Comment: Yup, I just would like to have a navigation bar at top showing the title. They way you told works like a charm. is there any other way where I do not have to embed my view controller in Navigation controller.

Comment: Drag a navigation bar to your view controller and set constraints.
override func loadView() {
        super.loadView() // do not forget this, or remove loadView() and move codes to viewDidLoad()
       ...
//        view = webView
        view.addSubview(webView) // use addSubview, not replace view. the views you drag to view controller is added to view, view = webView, will reset it.
  }
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
      var bounds = view.bounds
      bounds.origin.y = 44
      bounds.size.height -= 44
      webView.frame = bounds
}